# Create Client-side Unique Token Based On User Info

Tags: angular, uniqueidentifier

I need to create a client side recreatable token based on user info (IP, browser, or any other client side information).

This Token should be always same for a user that use same machine and same IP.

Comment: client side unique token is not advisable. What if the user logins through 3 different IPs, different browsers. what else you can take macAddress! not advisable option

Comment: So what do you recommend to do? I need to log clients login attempts. I found [this](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) ?

Comment: Why do you need for login attempts an unique identifier of the user? Is the username not unique?

Comment: It is for anonymous login attempts not for the one with username.